# How can I use keyple API to emulate a badge with NFC-enabled smartphones?

Tags: android, django, nfc, calypso

I'm working on a project which purpose is to emulate a badge using calypso protocol on a smartphone (with an NFC chip) via website (eg django) or an android application in order to access university buildings without the badge but only with the phone.

I'm looking for some information on internet and I discovered that there are keyple api but I'm not sure if it works for my job. The question is: keyple api are ok for my aim? If so, it's better to develop a website or an android app?

Comment: Unless the access system has been designed to work with NFC Forum Type 4A Tags then you are probably not going to have any success. This is a very broad question and needs more focus and my understanding is that calypso is not compatible with ISO/IEC 14443 used by NFC.